# Front back a string in Java

Tags: java, string

Basically I'm looking to take a string and just alternate between front and back. For instance, let's say I have the following string.

```
Android
```

That would then be output like this:

```
adnidor
```

It would alternate between the front and back

```
First letter `a`
Last letter `d`
Second letter `n`
Second to last `i`
etc.
to give `adnidor` in the end
```

How could something like this be done?

=======

The final solution went like this:

```
String r = "";
String s = "android";
int i = 0;
int j = s.length() - 1;
while (i < j) {
    r += s.charAt(i++);
    if (i < j) {
        r+= s.charAt(j--);
    }
}
if (s.length() % 2 == 0) {
    int l = (s.length() / 2) - 1;
    int f = l + 1;
    r = r + s.charAt(f);
}
else {
    int l = ((s.length()) / 2);
    r = r + s.charAt(l);
}
```

Comment: Post your code.  If you don't have any yet try the `String` class.  Why is this tagged "encryption"?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Guess maybe it shouldn't be tagged encryption but basically I'm hashing a string in my app then to just make it even more confusing i planned to take the string run that and then add it to either the front of the back of the string and then when checking it i'll just take half of the string. If i were to just put the hashed string twice it'd be easily recognizable or even just reversing it so just trying to make it more confusing

Comment: Just use an easier salt, this isn't adding anything useful

Comment: `confusing != secure != encryption`

Comment: I'm not using this as encryption i'm hashing my string using bcrypt and then just to make it less obvious i am doing this and then just adding it to the end of my string. Then when I check the string i cut it in half disregarding this part and hash the inputted string and check it against the first half of this. I am only putting this on the end to look more confusing it's not part of the actual hashing and in fact is completely disregarded when actually checking in my app. I just want the key to look even stranger since it will be in a txt file on their sd

Comment: Couldn't you avoid the ugly final if/else by using `if (i <= j)` instead of `if (i < j)`?

Comment: True i guess that would be a much easier solution i overlooked that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String weird_transformation(String s) {
  r = "";
  int i = 0;
  int j = s.length() - 1;
  while (i < j) {
    r += s.charAt(i++);
    if (i <= j) {
       r+= s.charAt(j--);
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: That left out one char that being the middle so i added an if statement like the above thanks for the solution though!